# Find $f\colon \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ such that $f(z)=z+f(z^2)$ in a neighbourhood of $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations

> Find $f\colon \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ that respects
>
> $f(z)=z+f(z^2)$
>
> in a neighbourhood of $0$.

I've never seen a problem like this, so i haven't any idea for solving it.

Comment: The problem is likely asking for analytic functions. Is it? In that case $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$. Therefore $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n= z + \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{2n}$. This gives you relations between the coefficients: $a_0=0$ $a_1=1$, $a_2=a_1$, $a_3=0$, $a_4=a_2$, ... From which you can find the coefficients. Therefore $f(z)=z + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{2k}=z+\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}$

Comment: @Hellen Then we can solve $g(z) - g(z^2) = 0$ with $g(z) = f(z)-z-\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}$ not necessarily analytic.

Comment: @Hellen You went too fast in identifying $f$.

Comment: @Hellen: The punishment for your quickie answer in the comments section has already been delivered by fate $\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, around $0$,$$f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+\cdots,$$then$$a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+\cdots=a_0+z+a_1z^2+a_2z^4+a_3z^6+\cdots$$From this, you deduce nothing concerning $a_0(=f(0))$, but now you know that $a_1=1$. And you also know that $a_2=a_1=1$. And that $a_3=0$.  And that $a_4=a_2=1$. And so on. The general rule is: $a_n=1$ if $n$ is a power of $2$ and $0$ otherwise. That is$$f(z)=a_0+z+z^2+z^4+z^8+\cdots$$and this series converges if and only if $|z|<1$.

Comment: Can you explain me why around $0$,$$f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+\cdots,$$,please?

Comment: @L.A. Since you attached the `complex-analysis` tag to this question, I assumed that you were interested in an answer which had something to do with analytic functions. And if $f$ is analytic, that $f$ can be expressed as the sum of a power series around each point of its domain.